# Distribute N items over a Set at least once

Tags: c#, probability

Given is a set of N items in a dictionary and its occurrences associated with it.
Now I have to assign exactly X slots to each item based on its overall probability, but at least 1 Slot per item.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<char,int>();

        dict.Add( 'a' , 10 );   dict.Add( 'b' , 0 );
        dict.Add( 'c' , 4 );    dict.Add( 'd' , 1 );
        dict.Add( 'e' , 9 );    dict.Add( 'f' , 0 );

        var distributionMap = Distribute( dict , 40 );
    }

    public static Dictionary<T,int> Distribute<T>( Dictionary<T,int> occurMap , int slots )
    {
        var freeSlots = slots - occurMap.Count;
        var total = occurMap.Sum( x => x.Value );
        var distMap = new Dictionary<T,int>();

        foreach( var pair in occurMap )
        {
            var probability = (double)pair.Value / total;
            var assignedSlots = probability * freeSlots;

            distMap[ pair.Key ] = (int)( 1 + assignedSlots );
        }

        Debug.Assert( distMap.Select( x => x.Value ).Sum() == slots );

        return distMap;
    }
}
```

However the assert triggers, as the conversion from `double` to `int` truncates the probability at some point.

How do I map all the slot at least once to the items based on their count?

Comment: Probability is a fraction so it should be a fraction or multiply by 100 to get a percentage.  Total need to be cast to a double because c# will  convert pair.value/total to an integer if total is an integer.  You really want pair.value/total to be a non-integer.

Comment: Math.Ceiling() maybe?

Comment: @jdweng why would I need a percentage? Also the probabilizy is already a double as i cast one operant to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous approach assigns the remaining items based on the totalcount whereas it seems more reasonable to assign them based on their fractional part. For example if there is one last slot to assign, an item with 0.8 should rather get the last slot than an item with 45.3 (and that already got 45 slots before)

I would:

- initialize the slots with the integralpart of the computation and keep track of the remaining fractional parts
- then order the fractional parts for each item in descending order and assign them until no slots are left

A sample implementation would look like this:

```
public static Dictionary<T,int> Distribute<T>( Dictionary<T,int> occurMap , int slots )
{
    var freeSlots = slots -  occurMap.Count;
    var totalFreeSlots = freeSlots;
    var total = occurMap.Sum( x => x.Value );
    var distMap = new Dictionary<T,int>();
    var remainingSlots = new Dictionary<T,double>();

    foreach( var pair in occurMap )
    {
        var probability = (double)pair.Value / total;
        var assignedSlots = probability * totalFreeSlots;

        var integralPart = Math.Truncate(assignedSlots);
        var fractionalPart = assignedSlots - integralPart;                    

        distMap[ pair.Key ] = 1 + (int)integralPart;
        remainingSlots[pair.Key] = fractionalPart;
        freeSlots -= (int)integralPart;
    }   

    foreach (var pair in remainingSlots.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
    {
        if (freeSlots == 0)
            break;

        distMap[ pair.Key ]++;
        freeSlots -= 1;
    }             

    return distMap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a reasonable approach

Answer (score 0):

Because number of slots is a whole number and average frequency is not - after initial free slot distribution you might have free slots left (if you round frequency down) or might have assigned more slots than you really have (if you round up). Reasonable approach then is:

1. First distribute all slots according to frequencies rounded down (that is what you already do)
2. Then assign left slots one by one starting from the most frequent item (there cannot be more free slots left than total number of items).

Sample implementation:

```
public static Dictionary<T, int> Distribute<T>(Dictionary<T, int> occurMap, int slots)
{
    if(slots < occurMap.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not enough slots");

    var freeSlots = slots - occurMap.Count;
    var total = occurMap.Sum(x => x.Value);
    var distMap = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    var keysByProb = new Queue<T>();
    foreach (var pair in occurMap.OrderByDescending(c => (double)c.Value / total))
    {
        var probability = (double)pair.Value / total;
        var assignedSlots = probability * freeSlots;

        distMap[pair.Key] = 1+ (int)Math.Floor(assignedSlots);
        keysByProb.Enqueue(pair.Key);
    }
    var left = slots - distMap.Select(x => x.Value).Sum();
    while (left > 0) {
        distMap[keysByProb.Dequeue()]++;
        left--;
    }
    Debug.Assert(distMap.Select(x => x.Value).Sum() == slots);
    return distMap;
}
```